# displaying an array

Tags: c#

i am trying to compile this code about arrays and classes in visual studio 2010 but i am having problems when running it an error(consoleapplication.Carray does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments)is displaying, may someone tell me what wrong i am doing the code only displays and array or is there any way i can do it????
code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            CArray CArray;
            CArray nums = new CArray();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 49; i++)
                nums.insert(i);
            nums.displayElements();
        }
    }

    class CArray
    {
        private int[] arr;
        private int upper;
        private int numElements;
        public CArray(int size)
        {
            arr = new int[size];
            upper = size - 1;
            numElements = 0;

        }
        public void insert(int item)
        {
            arr[numElements] = item;
            numElements++;
        }
        public void displayElements()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= upper; i++)
                Console.Write(arr[i] + " ");

        }
        public void clear()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= upper; i++)
                arr[i] = 0;
            numElements = 0;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by telling us what the error or exception you are getting is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, several problems.  One you have a constructor that is requesting the size of the array, and your main program is not feeding that to the constructor.  This is also problematic because you are using the size of the array in your displayelements() loop.  This won't compile since your constructor takes an argument.  You need to, at the very least, change your Main() program so that it feeds the size of your array to the constructor, which you have defined in your class CArray.  Change the following:

```
            CArray nums = new CArray(50); //since 50 is the length of your array
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a constructor in your CArray class that takes an integer as a parameter (int size). You are not passing that value to your CArray class in your main method.

```
static void Main()
     {
      int size = 33; //<-- declare an integer "size"
      CArray nums = new CArray(size); // <-- make an array with a size of "size", in this case, 33
      for (int i = 0; i <= size-1; i++) // <-- fill the integer with "size" numbers
      nums.insert(i);
      nums.displayElements();                  
     }
```

i also would not hard code the size in the for loop you posted in your example.
right now you're saying for `(int i = 0; i <= 49; i++)` which basically ignores the size of the array you are supposed to pass along to the constructor. 
if you use the example i've posted, you will always have an array of x elements.
If you leave the `i <= 49` bit and your size is , lets say 100, then your displayElements method will print out the numbers from 0 to 49, followed by a whole bunch of 0's. I dont think that's what you want ^^

Comment: i am trying to use your method but i am still getting some error

Comment: sorry my bad its working perfectly though the console is not display its just flashing....

Comment: hm, i tried out the code and the console is printing out what it should, without flashing. it *should* work anyway, hope i helped!

Comment: thanks for the help let try to change console.write maybe in the display fuction